# uncheck the checkbox when your return to the application after you have exited

Tags: android

I have used a checkbox in my app that plays correctly across the activities. when it is unchecked and I exit the application and run it again, there is no problem and the checkbox stays unchecked. But when it is checked and the music is played and at this time I exit the application and again return to it, the checkbox is still checked. I do not want this. I want the checkbox to be unchecked every time I run the application.

THIS IS MY JAVA CODE:

```
checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk_box_music);
checkBox.setChecked(isMyValueChecked);
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("checkbox", ((CheckBox) view).isChecked());
editor.commit();
if(checkBox.isChecked()){

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," " , 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
startService(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, 
MyService.class));
}else{
stopService(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, 
MyService.class));
}
}
});
```

and there is an onDestroy() method as following:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
checkBox.setChecked(false);
}
```

but the problem keeps staying anyway, whether I change the value to false or true. I would be so much grateful if a guy helps me solve this.

Comment: @Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
   checkBox.setChecked(false);

}

Answer (score 1):

There a few ways of doing that, a simple way like Igmer Rodriguez said, you could do it when you resume your application. The reason your code is not working is probably because you are not fully exiting the application (Kill the app) so on `destroy()` is never called. If you "exit" the app by minimize it (assuming that is what you are doing), you would have to put the `checkBox.setChecked(false);` on the `onPause()` method.